# Ubuntu: OpenJDK 8 - Unable to locate package

Tags: apt

I was trying to install openJDK 8 however when I run the command

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk 
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree
Reading state
 information... Done 

E: Unable to locate package openjdk-8-jdk
```

I searched through the internet and see some one suggested to run below 2 command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Here is what I got:

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
Oracle Java (JDK) Installer (automatically downloads and installs Oracle > JDK7 / JDK8 / JDK9). There are no actual Java files in this PPA.
 ...

 gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpeqhvs8pe/secring.gpg' created
gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmpeqhvs8pe/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: requesting key EEA14886 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: /tmp/tmpeqhvs8pe/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key EEA14886: public key "Launchpad VLC" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
OK

$ sudo apt-get update
 ...
Err http:/ /ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden [IP: 172.16.255.22 3129]
Get:1 https:/ /rapture-prod.corp.google.com goobuntu-puppet-addons InRelease
Err http:/ /ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                     
  403  Forbidden [IP: 172.16.255.22 3129]
...
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
W: Failed to fetch http:/ /ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 172.16.255.22 3129]

W: Failed to fetch http:/ /ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden [IP: 172.16.255.22 3129]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Anyone knows what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The ppa you linked is for the Closed JDK from Oracle.  You can view the contents of the PPA here - https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

You can install that like

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Currently it doesn't look like any OpenJDK 8 packages are built in 14.04.  Please update your question with the version of Ubuntu you are running.  I assume you are running 14.04 because 14.10 and later have 8.

**UPDATE :** You could install it with this PPA it appears - https://launchpad.net/~openjdk-r/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Alternatively if you don't want to use a PPA for this you could upgrade to 14.10.  It does have it in the repositories.